# How can i get prettier to format my code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm trying to get prettier to work on vs code and I've tried setting it as default formatter, format on save, disable then enabling. But i opened json and it said i have an error on   "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
so i was wondering if maybe that was the reason its not working? does anyone know what to change? Or how to fix it?

```
{
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.classpath": true,
        "**/.project": true,
        "**/.settings": true,
        "**/.factorypath": true
    },
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "prettier.arrowParens": "avoid",
    "prettier.requireConfig": true,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "html.format.contentUnformatted": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this into `settings.json` and it worked

```
"editor.linkedEditing": true,
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "[jvascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
    "window.zoomLevel": -1
}
```